# What is the difference between source and destination sequence number in AODV?

Tags: routing, protocol-theory, ad-hoc-wireless

What is the difference between source sequence number and destination sequence number in RREQ packet in AODV?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, they are two different entities. They are completely independent of each other. A node's sequence number gets incremented either when it broadcasts a RREQ packet or when it is the destination node, before sending the RREP packet.